# Linear vs non linear regression

Tags: regression

I am working on a project about data which containing the chlorine levels measured at different points in the city, presence of foreign waterbody and the total number of cases of water borne diseases found at those points in the city. My task is to find if the number of water borne diseases in the city has any relation with the water chlorine and presence of foreign waterbody. I whipped up a quick scatter plot to find the relationship between dependent and independent variables and this is what it looks like. I did suspect some non linearity but i have no idea how to move forward with this. Nonlinear regression would be tricky as i only have about 60 samples. Any leads on where to look for? Here is my scatterplot, correlation matrix and distribution plot of the independent variable for some contex. The total represents total number of cases which was created by summing up 4 different diseases

[image: scatterplot for the dependent variables]
[correlation matrix[image: ][2]]

[image: correlation matrix]

Comment: When you write "found at those points in the city," does that imply your data is spatial?

Comment: Adding to @Durden 's note:  And, if it is spatial, you may have to account for that, but it could be hard with only 3 points.

Comment: "i only have about 60 samples" In standard terminology in statistics, you have a sample --- one sample, not 60 --- consisting of about 60 observations, or 60 data points. The number 60 is the size of the sample, not the number of samples.

Comment: @Durden my data is not spatial. It was measured at various zones but there are no coordinates involved

Comment: @MichaelHardy you're right! That slipped passed me.